# Flask redirect(urlfor()) doesn't reload the page

Tags: javascript, python, ajax, python-2.7, flask

I have a page with a button that makes a `ajax` `post` to a `flask` route. I'd like the route to compute a message (simplified by hardcoding for the example) and passes it back to another route and reloads the page the user is on. `redirect(urlfor())` does call the other route, but `render_template` seems not to be called as the page doesn't reload.

**init**.py

```
from flask import Flask, render_template, request, redirect, url_for

app = Flask(__name__)


@app.route('/second_route', methods=['POST'])
def second_route():
    print request.json
    return redirect(url_for('hello_world', message='test'))


@app.route('/')
def hello_world(message=None):
    return render_template('index.html', message=message)


app.run()
```

index.html

```
<html>
<head>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


    <script>
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $('#mybutton').click(function () {
                $.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                    url: "/second_route",
                    data: JSON.stringify({}),
                    success: [],
                    dataType: "json"
                });

            });
        });


    </script>
</head>
<body>
{{ message }}
<button id="mybutton" name="mybutton" type="button">Click Me!</button>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AJAX cannot handle a redirect response, afaik. You could, though, encapsulate `{{message}}` in a `<span id="message">`, identify the element, and do a jQuery `.html()` to insert custom text upon AJAX completion success.

```
$.ajax({
   type: "POST",
   contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
   url: "/second_route",
   data: JSON.stringify({}),
   success: [],
   dataType: "json"
}).done(function(){
   $('#message').html('test');
   window.location.href = '/';
}).fail(function(response){
   $('#message').html(response['responseText']);
});
```

To redirect, you'd replace the code inside the `done` clause with `window.location.href = "/someURL"`, but since the endpoint is the same this isn't necessary. This way, using a `message` variable at all wouldn't be necessary.

Comment: so this was a simplified example. `second_route` is used to push data to a database. `message` is used to return the success of that data and reloading the page will requery a bunch of stuff from the database, so the `done` function with the div tag (while works in this example) will not work in my application. if I used `window.location.href` then I wouldn't have access to the message. Sorry my simple example oversimplifies things.

Comment: just to clarify, are you querying the database when loading `index.html` initially? I think including both was what you needed. Included clause in case AJAX call ran into an error.

Comment: I'm not sure save the message in `done` then reloading the `/` route works because that overwrites the message.

Comment: Yes I am querying initially

Comment: is anything from the database being rendered to the template? because if so, then you could re-query the database after you've pushed data to it in the same route, and return a `JSON` object (which could incorporate success or failure text) . This wouldn't reload the page, however (which at this point, depends if that's desirable or not)

Comment: it wouldn't reload the page, but it would update the page without having to refresh

Comment: yeah I that might work. I think maybe the easiest approach for my application would be to just post to the same route that loads the page

Comment: alright, let me know how that works. I'm interested in your approach as well. good luck!

Comment: added my solution as an answer. check it out.

Answer (score 1):

This is how I ended up solving the issue for those reading the question.

Changing my post request to post to the same route the loads the page with this call:

```
 var posting = $.post(window.location.href, {'some key': 'some value'});
                posting.done(function( ) {
                    window.location.replace(window.location.href);
                });
```

Comment: Ah that's how it's done. the `window.location.replace()` was new to me. guess we both learned something! UV'd